# How to host Jazzy documentation on Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, jazzy

I have generated documents for my application with [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy).
now I want to add a link to `index.html` file which is generated by Jazzy and it's the main page of the documentation in `README.md` file.
the problem is when I create a link addressing `index.html` file it only shows me the source file. I want it to be rendered as website.

Is there anyway through this?

P.S. my bitbucket repository is a private one. and we're running a local application of Bitbucket in our local network.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the documentation (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html)?

Comment: maybe that's because the `Https`, as they've mentioned  
`Please note that HTTPS is required for bitbucket.io for your security.`
I'm using `Http`

Comment: It redirects http to https with status 301. Are you getting another status? If so, what exactly are you getting?

Comment: I can't do it because I'm not using a repository on [Bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org) website. we're running a local application of Bitbucket in our local network. so it's not possible at all to use the .bitbucket.io to host a website.

Comment: That makes a big difference, then, and you could have saved yourself some time by mentioning that up-front.